# printing a JavaScript form to a console

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML code with JavaScript. I set the form to print to a console. My problem is that when it prints multiple selections or check boxes it still prints the comma after the last selection. Example "red, white," I would like the comma after the white not to print.
Please advise on how to get rid of the last comma.
Thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Extra Credit</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function onConsole()
        {
            var select = document.getElementById('colorSelect').value;
            console.log("Drop-Down: " + select);

            var a = " ";
            var multi = document.getElementsByName('multiColor')
                for(i=0; i < multi.length; i++)
                {
                    if(multi[i].selected === true)
                    {
                        a = a + multi[i].value + ", ";  
                    }
                }
                console.log("Multi-Select: " + a);

                var b = " ";
                var box = document.getElementsByName('checkboxColor')
                for(i = 0; i < box.length; i++)
                {
                    if(box[i].checked === true)
                    {
                        b = b + box[i].value + ", ";
                    }
                }
                console.log("Checkboxes: " + b);

            var radio = document.getElementsByName('radioColor')
                for(i=0; i < radio.length; i++)
                {
                    if(radio[i].checked === true)
                    {
                        console.log("Radio Button: " + radio[i].value);
                    }
                }              

            var text = document.getElementById('textArea').value;
            console.log("Text Area: " + text);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>    

    <form name= "ColorForms" action="InClass.html" method="post" onSubmit="onConsole()">

        <select id="colorSelect">
            <option>Choose a Color</option>
            <option value="red">red</option>
            <option value="white">white</option>
            <option value="blue">blue</option>
            <option value="orange">orange</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>

        <select multiple>
            <option value="red" name="multiColor">red</option>
            <option value="white" name="multiColor">white</option>
            <option value="blue" name="multiColor">blue</option>
            <option value="orange" name="multiColor">orange</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxColor" value="red">red<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxColor" value="white">white<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxColor" value="blue">blue<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxColor" value="orange">orange<br>

        <br><br>

        <input type="radio" name="radioColor" value="red">red<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioColor" value="white">white<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioColor" value="blue">blue<br>
        <input type="radio" name="radioColor" value="orange">orange<br>       

        <br><br>

        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textArea"></textarea>

        <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't add the `", "` when `i === box.length - 1`.

Comment: Put everything in an array, and use `array.join(', ')` to make a comma-separated list.

Comment: `if(multi[i].selected === true && i === multi.length-1){a = a + multi[i].value;}`

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith last element needs not be selected.

Comment: @Cthulhu isn't that what `multi.length-1` means?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith i mean literally the last element in the array may be unselected, then you will still end up with a coma after the last element in the string.

Answer (score 1):

In general, what you do now is

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'], str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    str += array[i] + ', ';
}
```

and of couse this adds comma after each element, including the last.

You should probably use Array method [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) which inserts string between elements, like:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    str = array.join(', ');
```

or closer to your case

```
var multi = document.getElementsByName('multiColor'),
    values = Array.from(multi).filter(function (el) {
        return el.selected;
    }).map(function (el) {
        return el.value;
    }),
    a = values.join(', ');
console.log("Multi-Select: " + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trim the comma off the end of your strings as below.

```
if (a.substr(a.length - 1, 1) === ",") {
    a = a.slice(0, a.length - 1);
}
```

Or you could not add the final comma in the first place by using the code below.  Either option will work fine.  Unless you are looping through hundreds of items in which case trimming the final comma from the string after the loop would be most efficient.

```
a = a + multi[i].value + (i===multi.length ? "":", ");
```

Comment: This option worked really well for multiple selections. Except in the case of one selection it shows a comma

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I have had a lot of great input